# how to add multiple items into ItemsSource WPF multiple collection binding?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, listbox, wpf-controls

I have added single item into `ItemsSource` which is a folder path and all the images will be added into `ListBox` but I want to add more items into existing `ListBox` using same `ItemsSource` how to do this?

```
List<string> folders = new List<string>();
    private void ComboBox1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
folders.AddRange(Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"C:\Users\images1", "*.*").ToList());
        imageItems.ItemsSource = folders;            
    } 

    private void ComboBox2_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
folders.AddRange(Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"C:\Users\images2", "*.*").ToList());
        imageItems.ItemsSource = folders;        
    } 

    <ListBox x:Name="imageItems" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Image Source="{Binding}" Width="120" Height="120"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

But only `ComboBox2_Loaded` item gets added and displayed not `ComboBox1_Loaded`
how can I get both the items?

Comment: Instead of `List<string>` use `ObsevableCollection<string>`, which implements `INotifyCollectionChanged` interface. It doesn't have `AddRange` so will need to add items one by one

Comment: you create `folders` only once since then you only change items in that list and because of that `imageItems.ItemsSource = folders` has not effect as it's still same list. If you don't recreate list you need to list which notifies UI when items in collection have changed and `ObsevableCollection<T>` does exactly that

Comment: thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to create a list that can be changed to store your file names in:

```
ObservableCollection<string> folders = new ObservableCollection<string>();
```

From there, you can add and remove all the items you want:

```
imageItems.ItemsSource = folders;

foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"C:\Users\images1", "*.*"))
{
    folders.Add(file);
}

foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"C:\Users\images2", "*.*"))
{
    folders.Add(file);
}
```

Comment: yes i did the same but it does not work if both are separate :( files added but not displayed . updated question

Comment: My mistake, you'll need to use an ObservableCollection instead. I'll update my answer. Also, you only need to set ItemsSource once.

Comment: `ToList()` isn't necessary in the foreach statements. I've edited the answer.